# 4 button captions through Loop from table recordset in vba access

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I have a form named frmPUCFinalize with four buttons named btn1,btn1,btn2,btn4 and also have a table (tblStatus) where 4 caption name are stored in single field named "Button".

I want to replace all 4 buttons captions of frmPUCFinalize with each recordset from table field (Field Name : Button) using loop or other method.

I tried following code but couldn't succeed.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim mSQL As String
mSQL = "SELECT tblStatus.Button FROM tblStatus WHERE (((tblStatus.RoleID)=4) AND ((tblStatus.Form)='frmPUCFinalize')) ORDER BY tblStatus.Button;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mSQL)

            x = 1
            Y = 4 'maximun 4 buttons

            rst.MoveFirst

            Do While (rst.BOF = False And rst.EOF = False) And x < Y + 1
                Me("btn" & x).Caption = rst!Button
                x = x + 1
                rst.MoveNext
            Loop
        rst.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `couldn't succeed` mean? Does not look too bad at first glance.

Comment: I just created a table `tblStatus` with the same fields as in your query, entered 4 Button texts, created a form `frmPUCFinalize` with four buttons named `btn1`, `btn2`..., pasted your code in the `Form_Load()` event - and it worked perfectly. Does your table have the correct data in it? Please provide more info. Cannot reproduce any error.

Comment: Thanks LocEngineer... I Solved the issue... just deleted Order BY Statement from mSQL statement and it worked perfectly for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim mSQL As String
    Dim idx As Long

    mSQL = "SELECT tblStatus.Button FROM tblStatus WHERE (((tblStatus.RoleID)=4) AND ((tblStatus.Form)='frmPUCFinalize')) ORDER BY tblStatus.Button;"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mSQL)
    If rst.EOF Then 
        rst.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With rst
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    For idx = 1 to rst.RecordCount
        Me.Controls("btn" & idx).Caption = rst![Button]
        rst.MoveNext
    Next idx

    rst.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas K.... It worked after changes in last Statement of mSQL ie ORDER BY tblStatus.Button.. I deleted it and worked perfectly... Great Job.. Kostas K.